# \newtotcounter with macro inside definition

Tags: counters, auxiliary-files, totcount

I tried to define `\newtotcounter`s (from `totcount` package) procedurally, as `bar\thefoo` where `foo` is another counter (details in MWE below). However, only the last `\newtotcounter` works as intended, while all the others don't show correct `\totvalue` (as if additional compilation was needed) and even multiple compilations do not solve this. However, if I change `\newtotcounter{bar\thefoo}` to `\newtotcounter{bar0}` and `\newtotcounter{bar1}` respectively, everything works as intended. Moreover, plain `\value` of both counters behaves normally, just as with plain `\newcounter`. It seems that when `totcount` is trying to save new totcounters in the auxiliary files it actually overrides previous values (it sees string `bar\thefoo` in both cases instead of `bar0` first and `bar1` second?). How can I prevent this?

MWE (2 totcounters are shown here and only the second works, with more counters only the last one works):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{totcount}
\newcounter{foo}
\newtotcounter{bar\thefoo}
\setcounter{bar0}{5}

\stepcounter{foo}
\newtotcounter{bar\thefoo}
\setcounter{bar1}{6}

\begin{document}

value of bar0: \the\value{bar0}

totvalue of bar0: \the\totvalue{bar0}

value of bar1: \the\value{bar1}

totvalue of bar1: \the\totvalue{bar1}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your example the name of the totcounter to be created is obtained and written to the .aux-file at the end of the LaTeX-run when all incrementing/stepping of the counter `foo` is already accomplished.

Try s.th. like `\expanded{\noexpand\newtotcounter{bar\thefoo}}` or `\expanded{\noexpand\newtotcounter{bar\number\value{foo}}}` so that the value of `foo` and thus the name of the totcounter to be created is obtained at the time of processing the command `\newtotcounter`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{totcount}
\newcounter{foo}
\expanded{\noexpand\newtotcounter{bar\number\value{foo}}}
\setcounter{bar0}{5}

\stepcounter{foo}
\expanded{\noexpand\newtotcounter{bar\number\value{foo}}}
\setcounter{bar1}{6}

\begin{document}

value of bar0: \the\value{bar0}

totvalue of bar0: \the\totvalue{bar0}

value of bar1: \the\value{bar1}

totvalue of bar1: \the\totvalue{bar1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(But this expansion-trickery does not resolve problems that might arise with totcount 2011/01/25 v1.2 when doing  `\newtotcounter/\regtotcounter[auxfile=⟨file⟩]{⟨counter⟩}` several times for denoting several different aux-files.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\newtotcounter` allocates the “total” version at end document, so `\thefoo` is expanded too late.

Actually, it should be `\arabic{foo}` to be really sure that you get a number and not another kind of representation.

So you need to do the expansion at the time `\newtotcounter` is performed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{totcount}

\newcommand{\newlinkedtotcounter}[2]{%
  % #1 = name for the linked totcounter, #2 = name of the parent counter
  % for older TeX systems
  %\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\newtotcounter{#1\arabic{#2}}}}\x
  % for newer TeX systems
  %\expanded{\noexpand\newtotcounter{#1\arabic{#2}}}%
  % for up-to-date TeX systems
  \ExpandArgs{e}\newtotcounter{#1\arabic{#2}}%
}

\newcounter{foo}
\newlinkedtotcounter{bar}{foo}
\setcounter{bar0}{5}

\stepcounter{foo}
\newlinkedtotcounter{bar}{foo}
\setcounter{bar1}{6}

\begin{document}

value of bar0: \the\value{bar0}

totvalue of bar0: \the\totvalue{bar0}

value of bar1: \the\value{bar1}

totvalue of bar1: \the\totvalue{bar1}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here, I expand the argument to `\newtotcounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\Bar{bar}
\usepackage{totcount}
\newcounter{foo}
%\newtotcounter{bar\thefoo}
\expandafter\newtotcounter\expandafter{\expanded{bar\thefoo}}

\stepcounter{foo}
%\newtotcounter{bar\thefoo}
\expandafter\newtotcounter\expandafter{\expanded{bar\thefoo}}

\begin{document}
totvalue of bar0: \the\totvalue{bar0}

totvalue of bar1: \the\totvalue{bar1}

\setcounter{bar0}{5}
\setcounter{bar1}{6}

value of bar0: \the\value{bar0}

value of bar1: \the\value{bar1}

\end{document}
```

[image]