# Printing the value of a counter (that is indexed by another counter) before it is set

Tags: counters, totcount

For the purposes of a MWE I have simplifed my problem to essentially displaying the number of fruits in a fruitshop *before* the fruits are counted. I am aware of the totcount package and this is my attempt of using it. I have a feeling that since the counters are being indexed by the fruitshop number, some issues are caused in its implementation.

Indeed, the code will run succesfully if I declare

```
\newtotcounter{fruitcounter1}
\newtotcounter{fruitcounter2}
```

as opposed to

```
\newtotcounter{fruitcounter\thefruitshop}
```

but the goal is to have the counters indexed by the fruitshop (suppose we do not know how many fruit shops we will visit).

I am aware of similar applications such as in the exam class, but the ability to count fruits through the \fruits{x} function is quite important for my application. Ideally the code in the main document **cannot** be changed. Does anyone have a solution for counting the fruits? My code is displayed below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{totcount}


\newcounter{fruitshop}
\setcounter{fruitshop}{1}

\newcommand{\visit}{
\vspace{0.5cm}
\newtotcounter{fruitcounter\thefruitshop}

\textbf{Fruit Shop Number \arabic{fruitshop}} that contains \total{fruitcounter\thefruitshop} fruits): 

\renewcommand{\fruits}[1]{
    #1\addtocounter{fruitcounter\thefruitshop}{#1}
}
}
\newcommand{\leave}{
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    We saw a total of \arabic{fruitcounter\thefruitshop} fruits! Would have been nice to see that number before entering the shop...
    \stepcounter{fruitshop}
}

\title{Fruit Counter}
\begin{document}

\visit 
There are \fruits{6} berries and \fruits{2} apples here. 

\leave

\visit 
Wow, there are \fruits{5} bananas here! 
\leave

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: There are several issues with your code; certainly just replacing the `\newtotcounter` definition would not have solved them. For example, you use `\renewcommand\fruits` without having first defined `\fruits`, and that would throw an error. And defining a `\renewcommand` inside a macro definition requires you to use `##1` instead of `#1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **main issue** related to the use of `\newtotcounter` is essentially one of expansion. You want to expand `\thefruitshop` before passing it to `\newtotcounter`.

There are some [other issues with your code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694920/printing-the-value-of-a-counter-that-is-indexed-by-another-counter-before-it-i#comment1725007_694920) which I have also fixed along the way.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{totcount}


\newcounter{fruitshop}
\setcounter{fruitshop}{1}

\newcommand\fruits{}

\newcommand{\visit}{
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\newtotcounter{fruitcounter\thefruitshop}}\x

\textbf{Fruit Shop Number \arabic{fruitshop}} that contains \total{fruitcounter\thefruitshop} fruits): 

\renewcommand{\fruits}[1]{
    ##1\addtocounter{fruitcounter\thefruitshop}{##1}
}
}
\newcommand{\leave}{
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    We saw a total of \arabic{fruitcounter\thefruitshop} fruits! Would have been nice to see that number before entering the shop...
    \stepcounter{fruitshop}
}

\title{Fruit Counter}
\begin{document}

\visit 
There are \fruits{6} berries and \fruits{2} apples here. 

\leave

\visit 
Wow, there are \fruits{5} bananas here! 
\leave

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the errors (`#1` should be `##1` twice and `\fruits` has to receive a definition in the preamble), the `.aux` file shows

```
\relax
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@fruitcounter3@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{fruitcounter3@totc}\fi\setcounter{fruitcounter3@totc}{0\c@fruitcounter3 }
\expandafter\ifx\csname c@fruitcounter3@totc\endcsname\relax\newcounter{fruitcounter3@totc}\fi\setcounter{fruitcounter3@totc}{0\c@fruitcounter3 }
```

so you see that the total counter's names are messed up. What you need is

```
\ExpandArgs{e}\newtotcounter{fruitcounter\thefruitshop}
```

so that `\thefruitshop` is fully expanded at definition time. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/587615/4427 for a similar problem.

Full code, with several other fixes, in particular the moment when the counter is stepped (and also formatting and protection of endlines):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{totcount}

\newcounter{fruitshop}

\newcommand{\fruits}[1]{%
  #1\addtocounter{fruitcounter\thefruitshop}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\visit}{%
  \par\addvspace{0.5cm}%
  \stepcounter{fruitshop}%
  \ExpandArgs{e}\newtotcounter{fruitcounter\thefruitshop}%
  \textbf{Fruit Shop Number \arabic{fruitshop}} (that contains 
  \total{fruitcounter\thefruitshop} fruits): 
}

\newcommand{\leave}{%
  \par\addvspace{0.5cm}
  We saw a total of \arabic{fruitcounter\thefruitshop} fruits! Would have been
  nice to see that number before entering the shop...\par
}

\title{Fruit Counter}
\begin{document}

\visit 
There are \fruits{6} berries and \fruits{2} apples here. 

\leave

\visit 
Wow, there are \fruits{5} bananas here! 
\leave

\end{document}
```